# How to divide a dictionary into two

Tags: c#, dictionary

How can i divide one dictionary items into two separate dictionary. For example..

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

dictionary.Add("cat1", 1);
dictionary.Add("dog2", 2);
dictionary.Add("cat3", 3);
dictionary.Add("dog4", 4);
dictionary.Add("cat5", 5);
dictionary.Add("dog6", 6);
dictionary.Add("cat7", 7);
dictionary.Add("dog8", 8);
dictionary.Add("cat9", 9);
dictionary.Add("dog10", 10);
...
dictionary.Add("dog100", 100);
```

this "dict" contains 100 items. But i need to separate first fifty and last fifty items in two different dictionary, Like..

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
Dictionary<string, int> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Please guide me..

Thanks

Comment: In a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, there is no such thing as "first fifty" and "last fifty". The order of the items in the dictionary is undefined, and could change with any modification of the dictionary. Whatever it is you _do_ actually want, surely it would not have been hard for you to try _something_. Then you could at least provide a [mcve] that shows what you tried, which would help us understand (possibly) what your _precise_ goal is, and what kind of answer is best. You got one option below, and maybe that will work, but there are lots of ways to interpret the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's split a dictionary into `N` ones (generalized problem; the last chunk can be bigger than others) with a help of modular arithmetics:

```
   Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = ...

   int N = 2;
   int mod = dictionary.Count / N;

   Dictionary<string, int>[] result = dictionary
     .Select((pair, index) => new {
        index = index,
        pair = pair,  
      })      
     .GroupBy(item => item.index / mod > N - 1 ? N - 1 : item.index / mod) 
     .Select(chunk => chunk.ToDictionary(item => item.pair.Key, item => item.pair.Value)) 
     .ToArray();

    Dictionary<string, int> dict1 = result[0];
    Dictionary<string, int> dict2 = result[1];
```

Comment: Perfect working fine. Nice solution Thanks a Lot!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict1 = dict.Take(50).ToDictionary(c=>c.Key, c=>c.Value);

Dictionary<string, int> dict2 = dict.Skip(50).ToDictionary(c=>c.Key, c=>c.Value);
```

With order (Assuming that you want to order the `value` part which is an `integer` in your example:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict1 = dict.OrderBy(c=>c.Value).Take(50).ToDictionary(c=>c.Key, c=>c.Value);

Dictionary<string, int> dict2 = dict.OrderBy(c=>c.Value).Skip(50).ToDictionary(c=>c.Key, c=>c.Value);
```

Comment: You'll need an OrderedDictionary to preserve the order, which I assume OP wants.

Comment: I'd just say: `var dict1 = dict.Take(50).ToDictionary....;` instead of first initializing.

Comment: @Jokab it will maintain the sequence of values in which order they were added in Dictionary unless OP doesn't update value(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't prefer `Linq`, have fun with this:

```
var firstHalf = new Dictionary<string, int>();
int i = 0, count = dictionary.Count;
foreach (var item in dictionary.Keys.ToList())
{
     firstHalf.Add(item, dictionary[item]);
     dictionary.Remove(item);
     if (++i == count / 2) break;
}
```

Note that the original dictionary, `dictionary`, will now contain only the second half of what was in it before.